# Find a finite generating set for $Gl(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, linear-groups

I need to find a finite generating set for $Gl(n,\mathbb{Z})$. I heard somewhere once that this group is generated by the elementary matrices - of course, if I'm going to prove that $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ has a finite generating set, I would need to prove that any matrix $M\in  GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ can be generated by only finitely many of them.

At first, I didn't have a clue as to how to do this, so I did a bit of scouring the internet for any information that might be useful. There were a few proofs or hints at proofs, including here on MSE and also on MathOverflow, but they were either too advanced, didn't give enough details, assumed theory I can't assume at this point (for example about rings or principle ideal domains), or were extremely complicated (as in 4 pages with 4 lemmas that needed to be proven first - and this example didn't even prove exactly what the finite generator of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is).

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181366/minimal-number-of-generators-for-gln-mathbbz) looks promising. In their notation, essentially, if $n$ is even, then $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $s_{1}$ and $s_{3}$ And when $n$ is odd, $-s_{1}$ and $s_{3}$ generate $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, where $s_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&\cdots &0&1\\ 1&0&0&\cdots & 0&0\\0&1&0&\cdots & 0 &0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots &\vdots \\ 0&0&0&\cdots & 0&0\\ 0&0&0&\cdots &1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $s_{3}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0&\cdots &0&0\\ 0&1&0&\cdots & 0&0\\0&0&1&\cdots & 0 &0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots &\vdots \\ 0&0&0&\cdots & 1&0\\ 0&0&0&\cdots &0& 1\end{pmatrix}$

How is a relatively simple way to prove this, that does not invoke rings or ideals at all (only group theory is permissible), and does not amake reference so to papers or $Hom(G,C_{p})$ (whatever that is)?

I'm guessing since the group operation in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is matrix multiplication, I'm guessing I'd have to show that any matrix $A$ can be generated by multiplying various combinations of $s_{1}$ and $s_{3}$ in the case when $n$ is even and various combinations of $-s_{1}$ and $s_{3}$ in the case when $n$ is odd. But what do those combinations look like when we're dealing with matrix multiplication? Do they include scalar multiples like integer linear combinations when the operation is addition? And how do we know what order to put them in, since matrix multiplication is not commutative?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you prove that $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}) =SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ the set of integers matrices with $\det M = \pm 1$ ? Then, think to the Gauss pivot, or reduce $M \in SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ to $\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ a & M' \end{pmatrix}$ and then to $\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & M'' \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @user1952009 that's not a true statement. $SL_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ is the set of integer matrices with $\det M =1$ only.  Also, please don't use block matrix notation - I find it confusing. This is not a linear algebra course, so I don't remember what a Gauss pivot is. Is that just regular row reduction with $1$'s in pivot positions and $0$'s above or below them?

Comment: @user1952009 no I didn't and didn't plan to. I will if I have to though. Is there a way you could explain it to me without that? And without referring to an adjugate matrix. Again, not a linear algebra course, we've never talked about it, so it's possible I've been using it and not even realized it was an adjugate matrix.

Comment: Yes I meant  $\{1,-1\} \times SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. You need the Gauss pivot, and understanding the adjugate matrix. You asked 10 questions about the same thing, so of couse you plan to do so. Also, show that $\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ generates $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then look at the case $n=3$

Comment: @user1952009 you're probably not going to respond, but I figured I'd try anyway. Nothing to lose. I posted an answer where I got to a certain point. Now, I'm stuck. I made the answer community wiki, so anybody who wants to can edit it. Could you please take a look and help me figure out where to go from there?

Comment: @user1952009 I deleted the answer. I'm trying to understand it for $n=2$ and $n=3$. Suppose I have $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} &  a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$. Suppose $a_{11} = 0$, then, in LeeMosher's notation, do $D_{2}S_{12}A = \begin{pmatrix}a_{21} & a_{22} \\ -a_{11} & -a_{12} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{21} & a_{22} \\ 0 & a_{12} \end{pmatrix}$ Now, my goal is to turn this into the identity matrix $I_{2}$, right? How do I do this from here??

Comment: @user1952009 and then if $a_{11} \neq 0$. Suppose also that $a_{21} \neq 0$, I'd say divide $a_{11}$ by $a_{22}$, but then $r = a_{11} - qa_{22}$, so should I then multiply the bottom row by $-q$ and add it to the first row? Then, what would that matrix be called using LeeMosher's terminology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple proof is: row reduction. Here's a brief outline, assuming some basic matrix algebra.

One learns in linear algebra or matrix algebra how to use row reduction to invert matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, to compute determinants, to solve systems of linear equations, etc. Essentially the row reduction algorithm from linear algebra tells us how to express an invertible real $n \times n$ matrix (an element of $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$) as a product of three kinds of matrices: (1) elementary matrices; (2) permutation matrices; and (3) diagonal matrices with nonzero elements on the diagonal. Doing a row operation corresponds to multiplying on the left by matrix of type (1); doing a row permutation corresponds to multiplying on the left by a matrix of type (2); and multiplying a row by a nonzero constant corresponds to multiplying on the left by a matrix of type (3).

For an element of $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ the same general method works, but there's some complications. First, the only diagonal matrices allowed are ones with $\pm 1$ on the diagonal. That makes it harder to get the numeral $\pm 1$ into a pivot position. But one can accomplish that using the Euclidean algorithm as a guide to producing an appropriate sequence of row reductions. The final result is that $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by: (1) elementary matrices with a $\pm 1$ entry off the diagonal; (2) permutation matrices; and (3) diagonal matrices with $\pm 1$ on the diagonal.

ADDED: Here's an example for the $2 \times 2$ matrix $\pmatrix{14 & -3 \\ 9 & -2}$.

I'll use row reduction notations like "$R_2 \to R_2 - R_1$" to represent "replace Row 2 by Row 2 minus Row 1". Here's a row reduction of the above matrix:
$$\pmatrix{14 & -3 \\ 9 & -2} \xrightarrow{R_1 \to R_1 - R_2} \pmatrix{5 & -1 \\ 9 & -2} \xrightarrow{R_2 \to R_2 - R_1} \pmatrix{5 & -1 \\ 4 & -1} \xrightarrow{R_1 \to R_1 - R_2} \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 4 & -1}
$$
$$\xrightarrow{R_2 \to R_2 - 4 R_1} \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1} \xrightarrow{R_2 -> - R_2} \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}
$$
If you wonder how I chose these row reductions, think of carrying out the Euclidean algorithm to compute the greatest common divisor of the entries in the first column.

Now, the instruction
$$A \xrightarrow{R_i \to R_i - R_j} B
$$
is equivalent to the matrix equation $E_{ij}^{-1} A=B$, equivalently $A = E_{ij}B$, where $E_{ij}$ is the elementary matrix with a $1$ in the $ij$ entry, and therefore $E_{ij}^{-1}$ is the elementary matrix with a $-1$ in the $ij$ entry. Also, the instruction
$$A \xrightarrow{R_i \to - R_i} B
$$
is equivalent to the matrix equation $D_i A = B$, equivalently $A=D_iB$, where $D_i$ is the diagonal matrix with 1's on the diagonal except for a $-1$ in the $(i,i)$ entry. In general examples you may also wish to use row swapping matrixes: the instruction to swap Row $i$ with Row $j$, written
$$A \xrightarrow{R_i \leftrightarrow R_j} B
$$
is equivalent to the matrix equation $S_{ij} A = B$, equivalently $A = S_{ij}B$, where $S_{ij}$ is the identity matrix with row $i$ and row $j$ swapped.

Thus we obtain a factorization
$$\pmatrix{14 & -3 \\ 9 & -2} = E_{12} \, E_{21} \, E_{12} \, E_{21}^4 \, D_2
$$

Comment: that seems a little confusing. I'll try it, but at first glance, I don't know how I'm going to get it to work. I hope you don't mind answering follow up questions.

Comment: As I said, it's a brief outline, particularly the third paragraph, and I can expand on something if there's any particular point you'd like to know more about. The row reduction stuff in second paragraph is a standard part of linear algebra, although from your comments above maybe you've missed out on it.

Comment: what matrix should I start with?

Comment: I.e. What matrix should I row reduce?

Comment: @LeeMosher I think it becomes clear when you show it with $n=2$ and $n=3$

Comment: The matrix you should row reduce is the matrix you are trying to factor.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: @LeeMosher there is no particular matrix I'm trying to factor.

Comment: Just to be clear, having a generating set for $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ means that for any $M \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ you can factor $M$ into a product of elements of the generating set. So when you asked "What matrix should I start with" or "What matrix should I row reduce", that general answer is "Whatever matrix $M$ that you want to factor into a product of elements of the generating set."

Comment: Also @LeeMosher what in general is the finite generating set you have shown that $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ has. The elementary matrices? And we know that this is a finite set how? (possibly a stupid question, but I need to know the answer in order to understand what's going on).

Comment: The sentence that starts with "The final result is that $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by..." answers your first question. Counting the matrices named in that sentence answers your second.

Answer (score 0):

The elementary matrices generate $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$. Use the row-switching transformations to reduce to the case $n = 2$. Then $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ is a finite-index subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$, and it's an amalgamated free product of two finite groups (see Serre's *Trees*, for example).

Comment: I know the elementary matrices generate $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$. I have no idea what a finite-index subgroup is. I have no idea what an amalgamated free product is or what a Serre's Tree is. Therefore, this answer is not useful to me at all. If you had showed me the mechanics of how to formally show specifically which elementary matrices generate it, etc. that would have been better.

Comment: So look it up and learn something new: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product . The point is that a finite set of elementary matrices generates all of $GL_(n, \mathbb{Z})$; finding an explicit such subset is not a good way of solving the problem.