# Index of an explicit subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_4(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, computer-algebra-systems, general-linear-group

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_4(\mathbb{Z})$ generated by the $4!$ permutation matrices together with
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

What is the index of $H$ in $\mathrm{GL}_4(\mathbb{Z})$? (I'm actually hoping the index is $1$.)

This seems like the sort of thing that GAP or some other software might be able to do directly, but I'm not familiar with the area. My motivation is that I've found certain symmetries on objects indexed by $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^4$ and I'm probing whether or not I've "found all of them."

Comment: Is there any kind of conceptual interpretation of that matrix?

Comment: @elemelons Not really. It is the matrix of the transformation $(a, b, c, d) \mapsto (a, c+d-a, b, d)$. My actual context involves pairs of pairs, $((a, b), (c, d))$, and this is a sort of "interchange" operation.

Comment: when you interchange the second and third column of your matrix, it looks more like an elementary matrix.

Comment: To do this by computer it would be helpful to have a presentation of ${\rm GL}(4,{\mathbb Z})$. I thought I had one somewhere but cannot find it!

Comment: One thing that is easy to do is reduce everything mod $p$ and look at the finite subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_4(p)$ generated. I did this for $p=2$ and the result is a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_4(p)$ of index $15$. So the index of $H$ is at least $15$.

Comment: ...and repeating for $p = 3, 5, \dots$ gives lower bounds of $80, 624, \dots$ (rapidly increasing). It looks like $H$ has infinite index.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I had thought about that, but the map $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is not surjective for $p>3$, since the image of the determinant is just $\pm 1$. On the other hand, the image has index $(p-1)/2$ for $p \neq 2$, so it's not far off.

Comment: @DerekHolt Here's [generators of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2129331/86777), at least. Not sure about their relations.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Right. I was computing the index in the subgroup $\det^{-1}(\{\pm1\}) \le \mathrm{GL}_n(p)$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Ah, of course, as your $p=5$ number implies. Thanks.

Comment: Notably, the indices I computed seem to be $p^4-1$, which does suggest that $H$ is the full stabilizer of $(1,1,1,1)^T$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group $H$ is reducible: it fixes the column vector $(1\ 1\ 1\ 1)^{\mathsf T}$.

So it has infinite index in ${\rm GL}(4,{\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: That answers the question! In my actual context, fixing $(c\ c\ c\ c)^\top$ isn't necessarily a bad thing, so I still wonder if $H$ is the stabilizer of this vector. If I knew a generating set for the stabilizer, I could at least project mod $p$ and throw Sage at it.